# oozie variables across action actions

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am new to oozie and have a usecase where we would need to set a variable in a oozie action and read the same variable in a different oozie action. This job runs every week and in first action we calculate few values and we like to use the same values in other actions as well,Just wanted to know oozie has provisions to do the same ?

Comment: If your original Oozie action supports `<capture_output/>` then, yes, you can output a list of _`key=value`_ pairs and use the values in other actions (in action properties, or in Decision expressions, or in Mail body text -- anywhere you can use an EL expression). Problem is, not all actions support that feature... Shell yes, Java yes, Spark no, etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks that's exactly I am looking for,I used <capture_output> and it worked!